# Long \mapsto-arrow

Tags: math-mode

Is there a longer version of `\mapsto`, like with `\rightarrow` and `\longrightarrow`? I found an ugly solution by inserting a couple of `\quad`s on top of `\xmapsto`, but it's not very elegant.

Comment: there is `\longmapsto`

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I have no idea what happened. I think I tried `\longmapsto`, but it failed, or something. When I tried to write my own `\longmapsto`, latex complained, and said it already existed. In essence, I messed up.

Answer (score 5):

I once needed some special integral signs and sort of 'faked' them using TikZ. You could do the same thing for your arrow. Here is an example:

```
\def\mylongmapsto#1{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0.5mm) -- (0,-0.5mm);
\newlength\mylength
\setlength{\mylength}{\widthof{#1}}
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (1.2\mylength,0) node[above,midway] {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\mylongmapsto{hello world}

\mylongmapsto{this is another long mapsto arrow}
```

it allows you to place text on top of your arrow and automatically scales it accortingly. Gives me the following results:

[image]

Comment: It appears that this works in text mode. How would one make this work in math mode, like the align environment, for example?

Comment: @BSplitter You can use `\xmapsto{Hello world}` with `\usepackage{mathtools}`. Maybe `\xmapsto{\phantom{Hello world}}` if you only want the big arrow without the text.